# Close JFrame pane when button is clicked

Tags: java, swing, button, jframe, dispose

I'm trying to use close the pane from an airplane seat system, so each passenger chooses only 1 seat. I researched and know I need a line of code JFrame.dispose(); But I don't know where to put it and what else to put it. Thoughts? (Other than that I'm a complete noob XD)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class APlaneJToggle {

private int rows = 15;
private int columns = 6;
private Icon res = (UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon"));

public APlaneJToggle() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(rows, columns));
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        String []rowChar = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};
        for (int column = 1; column < columns+1; column++) {

            final JToggleButton button = new JToggleButton(rowChar[row] + column);
            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                        AbstractButton abstractButton = (AbstractButton) actionEvent.getSource();
                        boolean selected = abstractButton.getModel().isSelected();
                        if (selected) {
                            button.setIcon(res);
                        } else {
                            button.setIcon(null);
                        }
                    }
                });
            panel.add(button);
        }
    }
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Flight");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocation(300, 100);
    frame.resize(750,450);
    frame.isDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                APlaneJToggle aPlaneJToggle = new APlaneJToggle();
            }
        });
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#getWindowAncestor(java.awt.Component)) to return the `Window` which a component resides in, this way you could `dispose` on the returned result.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private int rows = 15;
        private int columns = 6;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridLayout(rows, columns));
            for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
                String[] rowChar = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};
                for (int column = 1; column < columns + 1; column++) {

                    final JToggleButton button = new JToggleButton(rowChar[row] + column);
                    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                            AbstractButton abstractButton = (AbstractButton) actionEvent.getSource();
                            boolean selected = abstractButton.getModel().isSelected();
                            if (selected) {
                                button.setText("X");
                            } else {
                                button.setText("");
                            }
                            SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(button).dispose();
                        }
                    });
                    add(button);
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

You might consider using a `JDialog` instead of a `JFrame` as it will allow you to control the program flow better.  Have a look at [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details

Comment: Wow ok it works. I'll see if I can understand it by tonight though its already 1.17 am XD Tks a bunch

Comment: Panina don't forget me below. The panel doesn't work because you didn't initialize and add in a proper order. Download my code from the link below and you'll see that it works.

Comment: Omg this is ridiculous. I would hav never thought of it. I stll can't fully understand what it's doing, but u know sleep deprivation XD

Comment: The idea is simple enough, but the complexity is hidden in the `SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(button)`, which walks the container hierarchy to find the first instance of a top level container (or window) (simply calling `Component#getParent`).  Once you have a reference to this window (and since a component can only belong to a single container and you can't add windows to other containers, it has to be the parent window), you can call `dispose` which will go through the process of freeing the windows resources and closing it...

Answer (score 2):

Suggestions:

1. I'm guessing that you want to allow the user to only select one button. If so, then perhaps a better solution: use a ButtonGroup and add all the JToggleButtons to the single ButtonGroup. This way the user still can select another seat, but the previous seat will become unselected.
2. Use an ItemListener not an ActionListener if you go this route.
3. The calling code can easily get the selected button from the ButtonGroup object.
4. If this window will be displayed from another top level JFrame window, it is better off as a JDialog and **not** a JFrame.

---

For example (better late than never)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class APlaneJToggleTest extends JPanel {
   private DefaultListModel<String> seatListModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
   private JList<String> selectedSeatList = new JList<>(seatListModel);
   private JButton getSeatSelectionBtn = new JButton(new GetSelectionAction("Get Selected Button"));
   private JDialog getSeatDialog;
   private APlaneJToggle aPlaneJToggle = new APlaneJToggle();

   public APlaneJToggleTest() {
      selectedSeatList.setVisibleRowCount(8);
      String prototype = String.format("%20s", " ");
      selectedSeatList.setPrototypeCellValue(prototype);

      add(getSeatSelectionBtn);
      add(new JScrollPane(selectedSeatList));
   }

   private class GetSelectionAction extends AbstractAction {
      public GetSelectionAction(String name) {
         super(name);
         int mnemonic = (int) name.charAt(0);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         if (getSeatDialog == null) {
            Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(APlaneJToggleTest.this);
            getSeatDialog = new JDialog(win, "Choose Seat", ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            getSeatDialog.add(aPlaneJToggle.getMainPanel());
            getSeatDialog.setResizable(false);
            getSeatDialog.pack();
         }
         getSeatDialog.setVisible(true);
         ButtonModel model = aPlaneJToggle.getSelectedModel();
         if (model != null) {
            String actionCommand = model.getActionCommand();
            seatListModel.addElement(actionCommand);
            aPlaneJToggle.clear();
         }
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      APlaneJToggleTest mainPanel = new APlaneJToggleTest();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("APlaneJToggleTest");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

class APlaneJToggle {
   private int rows = 15;
   private int columns = 6;
   private Icon res = (UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon"));
   private Icon blankIcon;
   private ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
   private JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

   public APlaneJToggle() {
      int bi_width = res.getIconWidth();
      int bi_height = res.getIconHeight();
      BufferedImage blankImg = new BufferedImage(bi_width, bi_height,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
      blankIcon = new ImageIcon(blankImg); 
      JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(rows, columns));

      for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
         String[] rowChar = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J",
               "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W",
               "X", "Y", "Z" };
         for (int column = 1; column < columns + 1; column++) {

            String text = rowChar[row] + column;
            final JToggleButton button = new JToggleButton(text, blankIcon);
            button.setActionCommand(text);
            buttonGroup.add(button);
            button.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

               @Override
               public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                  Icon icon = e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED ? res
                        : blankIcon;
                  ((AbstractButton) e.getSource()).setIcon(icon);
               }
            });
            buttonPanel.add(button);
         }
      }
      JButton selectionButton = new JButton(new DisposeAction("Make Selection"));
      JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
      bottomPanel.add(selectionButton);

      panel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      panel.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
   }

   public void clear() {
      ButtonModel model = buttonGroup.getSelection();
      if (model != null) {
         model.setEnabled(false);
      }
      buttonGroup.clearSelection();
   }

   public ButtonModel getSelectedModel() {
      return buttonGroup.getSelection();
   }

   public JPanel getMainPanel() {
      return panel;
   }

   private class DisposeAction extends AbstractAction {
      public DisposeAction(String name) {
         super(name);
         int mnemonic = (int) name.charAt(0);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         Component comp = (Component) e.getSource();
         Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(comp);
         win.dispose();
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: well
1) hmm ok i'll prob test that out tomorrow if I can't get it to work
2) There is a main JFrame window however I thinking of using method calls later on. I'll do some further research

Comment: @PANINA: if it's a modal dialog, it will be **much** easier for the calling window's code to know when this window is no longer visible. Hang on.... code to follow.

Comment: Good suggestion for `ButtonGroup` +1

Comment: @MadProgrammer: thanks, and same to yours (although I cast that vote long ago). I have no idea why someone down-voted your correct answer though.

Comment: @PANINA: better late than never. Please see what I mean about using a ButtonModel object and a modal dialog in my code example above.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to close the application you could also use the `System` class.

```
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: no thats pointless to me and still i need them to actually press the button

Answer (score 0):

In **Netbeans**:-

1. Set the **defaultCloseOperation** to    **DISPOSE** from the properties
   of the JFrame.
2. then type **this.dispose()** inside the **ActionPerformed()** of the jButton.